# How to publish an OpenXR app in Microsoft Store

Tags: hololens, windows-store, openxr

I'm completely confused right now. We have an app for the Hololens 2 which uses OpenXR. The app itself works fine on the device (it was tested extensively by us and several of our customers) but currently we are using side-loading to get the app onto the headset.

As some or most of our customers are not really able to use side-loading we want to publish our app to the Microsoft Store in order to make it easier accessible for them.

So i associated the app with the name i reserved in the MS Store and when it ran the Windows App Cert Kit i got this as error (it's in german but the problem is we are using the openxr_loader.dll which is using APIs which are not part of the Windows Store API apparently):

```
API xrAcquireSwapchainImage in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrApplyHapticFeedback in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrAttachSessionActionSets in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrBeginFrame in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrBeginSession in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrCreateAction in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrCreateActionSet in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrCreateActionSpace in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrCreateInstance in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrCreateReferenceSpace in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrCreateSession in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrCreateSwapchain in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrDestroyAction in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrDestroyActionSet in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrDestroyInstance in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrDestroySession in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrDestroySpace in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrDestroySwapchain in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrEndFrame in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrEndSession in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrEnumerateEnvironmentBlendModes in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrEnumerateSwapchainFormats in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrEnumerateSwapchainImages in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrEnumerateViewConfigurationViews in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrGetActionStateBoolean in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrGetActionStateFloat in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrGetInstanceProcAddr in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrGetSystem in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrGetSystemProperties in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrLocateSpace in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrLocateViews in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrPollEvent in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrReleaseSwapchainImage in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrRequestExitSession in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrStringToPath in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrSuggestInteractionProfileBindings in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrSyncActions in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrWaitFrame in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
API xrWaitSwapchainImage in openxr_loader.dll wird für diesen Anwendungstyp nicht unterstützt. IPhysics_ARM64.exe ruft diese API auf.
```

So my question is: Is it even possible to publish an app in the MS Store if it uses OpenXR? And if it is, what do i need to do to get it to work?

Thanks in advance,

Christoph

Comment: I tested my Unity project and Open XR project, but I couldn't reproduce your problem. What tool/engine do you use to develop? Have you used the corresponding official sample to do some tests? And have you packed the project to the release version?

Comment: Hmmm interesting... We don't use a "ready-to-go" engine like Unity or something like it, we use our own hand-written renderer. Yes i double-checked that i used a release build with the App Cert Kit, because i read somewhere that this might be an issue... As i mentioned the app itself works like a charm if i side-load the app on the device or were you asking if i ran for example a unity/OpenXR-example through the app cert kit?

Comment: You can try to remove openxr_loader.dll from the package and then perform Windows App Certification Kit Test. When the application requires this library, users can download and install Open XR Runtime on Microsoft Store - [OpenXR for Windows Mixed Reality - Microsoft Store Apps](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/openxr-for-windows-mixed-reality/9P9596DJJ19R?hl=en-us&gl=us).